# How to validate XML against xsd in referenced DLL?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, biztalk

I have created a class library in which all the schema are added. 
The xsd schema have relative schemas (import/include).
The dll of this project is referenced in another application where I need to validate the input XML, using these referenced dll schema.

Please help me, how can I validate the xml using the referenced dll schema.

I am trying to implement this solution to Biztalk pipeline.

Comment: Is this Assembly a BizTalk assembly?

Comment: yes, I have created a custom library and reference it to biztalk assembly

Comment: Sorry, this is very important.  Are the Schemas compiled into a BizTalk Assembly as BizTalk Schemas or a regular C# Class Library?  The latter will not work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the schemas are properly deployed to BizTalk, you should be able to use the [XML Validator component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578187.aspx).

Just set the document collection to include the schema(s) for the messages you want to validate.  The runtime will be able to determine what schema(s) to use by the `BTS.MessageType` (`namespace#rootnode`), regardless of what assembly they're deployed in (again, as long as they're properly deployed to the BizTalk database).

Comment: I added the XML Validator, to the receive pipeline, and now I am getting this error, **There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "MailReader.AttachmentsExtractorPipeline, MyBiztalk.MailReader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=da3246340865108f" Source: "XML validator" Receive Port: "ReceiveMailAttachment" URI: "POP3://abc.test.com#mailingaddress.test" Reason: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.**

Comment: Without XML Validator, it works fine, But after adding the XML Validator it gives the above error

Comment: That should mean the message doesn't validate against the schema.  Test out the instance, try to validate it in visual studio against your schema.  Chances are there's an attribute that's wrong or a missing namespace qualification.

Comment: I validated the instance of the input xml against the schema in Visual Studio and it has no error.

Comment: I have included 3 xsd schemas in the DocumentSpecName. One is the main schema and other 2 are the included schemas for the first one.

Comment: Have you included the XML Disassembler component (or Flat File disassembler) at the disassemble stage?

Comment: No, I have Included the XML Validator in the Decode stage, and then the Custom pipeline for receiving email in the Disassembler stage.

Comment: Check the output of your custom disassembler against the schema?

Comment: No, How can I do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104184/discussion-between-dan-field-and-user3615920).

Answer (score 1):

Validating the message against input schema:
1st method

1. Use XML receive pipeline :

   a.       Set validate schema to true.

   b.      Document Spec Name should be the fully qualified schema name.
2. Create custom pipeline and put XML dissembler and dissemble stage and XML validate in validate stage